# Why won't the Link change size despite the Div being smaller?

Tags: html, css

Right so I am relatively new to all this and took a six month break from doing anything at all, so my memory is pretty off anyhow but I've been trying for ages now to make it so that the link for the Navigation will fit inside the grey box (background image shows the box) but it won't change size no matter what I seem to try. It is probably something so simple that I've done wrong or missed but any help would be much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt'           rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nova+Mono'   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <style>
        * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/yFlnLhy.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 5%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 11%;
        left: 0;

overflow: auto;
       }
nav b {
font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
font-size: 1.5em;
position: fixed;
}
nav a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #98bf21;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1em;
}
header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 9%;
            position: fixed;
            font-family: 'Nova Mono', ;
            font-size: 200%;
        }
</style>
<title>
Site Title Here
</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    TITLE
</header>
<nav>
    <b>Links:<b>
    <a href="www.marapets.com">Home</a>
</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if  understand you right, but adding a margin of margin:0px 20px; should place it into the box area. 20px = apx. width of side border.

Comment: I just tried that but that just moved it 20px to the right and didn't reduce the size of it at all. Like, what I mean  is where I have the slightly darker bar for my Nav I want the links to be just slightly shorter than  that, but nothing I do seems to work?

Comment: cann you add this to fiddle?

Comment: It's because you're using em as a font-size. This means there basing there size off of a parent containers font-size, but this isn't being defined. I recommend placing a font-size on the body and size your b using em as you are. You can also just give the nav a font-size.

Comment: Thankyou very much - will give it a try now.